# Obtain page sourceCode

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt, xmldom

I have a page which contains a XSL as it's source code. Is there any way to get the page source code (as seen on right-click->show source code in IE)?

EDIT: The page source code IS a XSL! I need to store it in a variable to use later.

Comment: You may wish to update your question to include the comments you added to the answers below. I do not think your question clearly states that you wish to use Javascript to capture the document source in a variable.

Comment: Edited. I think it states that I need to obtain the code. Storing it into a variable is just a consequence.

Comment: You need to get the source code... from the page itself?

Comment: @zneak Yes!! I've tried with $("body").html() and it returned the HTML elements code (ofc!) of the page, but not it's real source code as seen on right click!!

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, the XML source seems to be irremediably lost in the transformation process. The simplest way I can think of is to use AJAX to query the page again. (On most browsers, this should be very fast because of caching.)

```
$.get(document.location, function(xml) { /* do something with xml */});
```

Comment: Nice attempt, but it still returning null! Zneak, maybe this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709172/ie-cant-create-activexobject) might help finding the answer. This is the real achievement that I'm trying to reach! But I must use the source code (obtained here) to replace in the document.XMLDocument.xml line. Many XML and XSL transformations happens in this system, it's a bit old, but still working, except for this bug! I can't rewrite it so much without affecting the other functions inside it :(

Comment: Is there something preventing you from using the `load` method on the XMLDOM object instead of the `loadXML`? `load` accepts an URL.

Comment: Hi Zneak! Using loadXML and load, still returning the error! I've been thinking to store somehow the generated XML and then call it by an AJAX request or something alike but that's a poor and dirty solution... :(

Answer (score 0):

Use a debugger, such as Firebug. It gives you access to the entire response.

Comment: But I need to store it in a variable to use it later!!

Answer (score 0):

XSL is to XML as CSS is to HTML. Both simply define styles for outputting markup data.

If the XSL transform is done in the browser, you could find the XSL file path in the source with a line similar to this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>
```

If that's what you're looking for, all you need to do is load that XSL document and view it.

More Info: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp

Comment: +1 to offset. Answers should be graded on merit. The value of w3schools is not directly relevant.

Comment: I think they can be useful for basic information.  If you have a better suggestion, I'll update my link.

Comment: It actually doesn't let me store the page source code (wich is a XSL) into a variable! :\

Comment: @Raynos warning about the w3fools is ok, but downvoting seems a bit unfair. (I would -1 only when the info on the answer is wrong)

Comment: @Raynos I agree that the W3 link has way more information, but judging from the content of the question, I figured it might be too complex to help him.